# installing haskell package gtkglext on mac

Tags: haskell, gtk, glib, gtk2hs

I would like to use **Graphics.UI.Gtk.OpenGL**

I have:

- OS X 10.11
- cabal version 1.22.0.0
- installed gtk

The error I get:

```
Could not find module ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.OpenGL’
  Perhaps you meant
    Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.GC (from gtk-0.14.2)
    Graphics.UI.Gtk.Cairo (from gtk-0.14.2)
    Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Gdk (from gtk-0.14.2)
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.`
```

I'm  trying to install gtkglext using:

```
cabal install gtkglext
```

But then I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring glib-0.12.5.4...
Building glib-0.12.5.4...
Failed to install glib-0.12.5.4
Build log ( /Users/Martin/.cabal/logs/glib-0.12.5.4.log ):
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     (         /var/folders/4p/yw17gzsd4554drxtxmbdd24c0000gn/T/glib-0.12.5.4-1526/glib-   0.12.5.4/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/4p/yw17gzsd4554drxtxmbdd24c0000gn/T/glib-0.12.5.4-1526/glib-0.12.5.4/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/4p/yw17gzsd4554drxtxmbdd24c0000gn/T/glib-0.12.5.4-1526/glib-0.12.5.4/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/4p/yw17gzsd4554drxtxmbdd24c0000gn/T/glib-0.12.5.4-1526/glib-0.12.5.4/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/4p/yw17gzsd4554drxtxmbdd24c0000gn/T/glib-0.12.5.4-1526/glib-0.12.5.4/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring glib-0.12.5.4...
Building glib-0.12.5.4...
Preprocessing library glib-0.12.5.4...
gtk2hsC2hs: Error in C header file.

/usr/include/dirent.h:150: (column 10) [FATAL] 
  \>>> Syntax error!
  The symbol `^' does not fit here.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gio-0.12.5.3 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
glib-0.12.5.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gtk-0.12.5.7 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
gtkglext-0.12.5.0 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
pango-0.12.5.3 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.`
```

**So what I found out is, gtkglext has dependency  glib (>=0.12.5.0 && <0.13),
and I cannot install glib version in this range because of this error, does it mean I can't use gtkglext?**

**EDIT:-------------------------------------------------------------------**

Installing with

```
cabal install gtkglext  --with-gcc=gcc-4.8
```

produces another error, which is:

`Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Structs.hsc:660:3:
    Couldn't match type ‘CInt’ with ‘Ptr a0’
    Expected type: IO (Ptr a0)
      Actual type: IO CInt
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Drawable drawable)
          -> withForeignPtr drawable gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid)
         (toDrawable d)’
    In the expression:
      liftM toNativeWindowId
      $ (\ (Drawable drawable)
           -> withForeignPtr drawable gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid)
          (toDrawable d)`

Little of googling produces:
https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/27

But I dont know how did he "have just disabled drawableGetID completely and that seems to work ok."

Any help would be useful.

Comment: `gtkglext` on Hackage was last uploaded in 2013, so it's probably out of date. You could try just editing the cabal file and remove the problematic bounds restriction and see it that works.

Answer (score 2):

The key is this error message:

```
/usr/include/dirent.h:150: (column 10) [FATAL] >>> Syntax error! The symbol `^' does not fit here.
```

Googling that message leads to his issue on github:

https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/1

The suggested fix is to run cabal with:

```
cabal install --with-gcc=gcc-4.8
```

So - perhaps upgrade your version of `gcc` and use the `--with-gcc=` flag if you need to.